# Installing git to be used in a multi-user system

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

I need to install git on a Ubuntu server that will be shared and accessed by multiple users.

I assume I will use git+ssh, so each user will have a system account, but how do I go about installing git and a repository so that each user can push/pull over a local IP?

Comment: Probably a candidate for http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single account on the server that owns the repository (as a bare repository).  Users do not get their own accounts, but get ssh access to this account by adding their public keys to .ssh/authorzed_keys.  Optionally you can restrict the rights of the users to only execute git-receive-pack (see section "AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT" in the sshd man page, assuming you are using OpenSSH).

This approach is less flexible than using gitosis, but might be easier to set up.